# How to create a simple interface to get file path and execute some code on it?

Tags: gui-construction, code-review

I need to create a simple user interface to choose one file in the notebook directory, import it and execute some functions on the imported data. For the first version I created this code:

```
Button["get File Path",
 fileData = Import@SystemDialogInput["FileOpen", NotebookDirectory[]];
 ];
 function[fileData]
```

Now I want it to be a little bit more error proof, so if you cancel your selection, you don't get an error, and the rest of your code is not executed.

```
Button["get File Path",
fileData=Quiet@Check[Import@SystemDialogInput["FileOpen",NotebookDirectory[]],$Canceled]
    ]
    If[fileData!=$Canceled,function[fileData]]
```

I don't feel that it is the best practice for this kind of situation.
Some clue to make the code more intelligent? Maybe with `Module`, `DynamicModule`, `Return` or something else?

Comment: For slow actions `Button` needs the option `Method->"Queued"` (see http://wolfram.com/xid/0mrh4y-k6ay1g)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you have to specify `file` for filename and only load `file` (with `load`, that can be e.g. `Import`), if file is not `$Canceled` (use `UnsameQ` instead of `NotEqual`). You have to put the loading after the test **inside** the button as well - after all, import should happen only *when the button is pushed and the user has chosen a valid file*. Also it is good practice to have initial values for `file`, `fileData` and `dir`. You can extract the actual directory that the user has chosen and feed it to `SystemDialogInput` so that next time the dialog is called it will open at the last used directory, for convenience.

After some adjustments:

```
fileData = {};
file = "";
dir = $UserBaseDirectory;

Button["get File Path",
 file = SystemDialogInput[
   "FileOpen", {dir, {"Mathematica files" -> {"*.nb", "*.m"}, "all files" -> {"*.*"}}}, 
   WindowTitle -> "Open Mathematica file..."];
 fileData = If[file =!= $Canceled, load[file], "Nothing"];
 ]
Dynamic@fileData
```

Comment: Nice!.. You got my point! Tks

Answer (score 6):

You could use `FileNameSetter` which seems a better choice for setting the path. If you have a `DynamicWrapper` containing your function call, it will be run every time the path is changed. When the user cancels, the path doesn't change, so it won't trigger anything or require special handling. Here I just use a dummy work function which prints the chosen files name.

```
function[file_]:=Print@FileBaseName@file

DynamicModule[{file = ""},
 DynamicWrapper[
 FileNameSetter[Dynamic[file], "Open", {"Notebook" -> {"*.nb"}}],
 If[file != "", function[file]]
]]
```

Comment: I get an error when I try to use your code. It happens when  I choose some file.

Comment: @Murta What error?

Comment: It prints the file name in the error dialog box, not in the notebook.